# how to solve this Error : Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement In Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```js
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await installMouseHelper(page);
  const cursor = createCursor(page);
  await page.goto('https://example.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await page.waitForTimeout(1500);  
  await cursor.move("input[id='year-2021']");
  await page.click("input[id='year-2021']");
```

Error Message Is Here
[image]

Here is Inspect Images  [image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to Select `<input type="radio" id="year-2021" name="year" class="pbpt4-1 nBNAEq" value="2021"> ` This Element